# Image loading from localhost is not working on silverlight

Tags: silverlight, image, silverlight-4.0, localhost

I making simple silverlight application.

I need to access and use an image from localhost,

I write down my code like this

Book4.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://localhost/test/book2.png", UriKind.Absolute));

It doesn't make any errors, but It can't load any image.

//P.S. I didn't use asp. It is OOB app.

* EDITED: To include additional content for the question.

```
 public void changeValue_book()
        {
            if (empty_book[3] == true && book_index == 3)
            {
                empty_book[3] = false;
                Book4.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                Book3.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            Book3.Source = null;
            Book3.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://localhost/test/book1.png", UriKind.Absolute));
            //Book3.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resource/책1.png", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        else if (empty_book[4] == true && book_index == 4)
        {
            empty_book[4] = false;
            Book5.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            Book4.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            Book4.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://localhost/test/book2.png", UriKind.Absolute));
        }
        else if (empty_book[5] == true && book_index == 5)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to access the expected image from your web browser by navigating to http://localhost/test/book2.png ?

Comment: I got a another answer like this.
I didn't access as http.
I used C:/inetpub/wwwroot as Source so, I complete my problem kk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to access the expected image from your web browser when you navigate to [http://localhost/test/book2.png](http://#) then try the following:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost/test/book2.png", UriKind.Absolute);
ImageSource imageSource = new BitmapImage(uri);
Book4.Source = imageSource;
```

**EDITED**

If you're images reside on http://localhost/test/yourimagename.png, but your Silverlight application is hosted within an **https://** or from the **Filesystem** you will not be able to load the images at all.  The Silverlight Image class and MediaElement class for progressive downloads (media, images, ASX, etc.) are not allowed Cross-scheme access.

Please see this link for more details:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189008(v=vs.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189008%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Help me understand what you mean when you say "But it doesn't work any more".  Did it work before and now it doesn't?  Can you access the image from your web browser?

Comment: It didn't work before too. and I can access this image from my web brower.

Comment: Are you creating the entire image element from code, or are you just assigning the src property of an image element that exists within your xaml file?  Please provide either the xaml or the rest of the code that you're using to create the image.

Comment: Thanks for including more source.  Where are Book3, Book4, Book5 all defined?  When do they get added to your view?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a new solution for setting the source for your image.  Give it a shot.

Comment: @David Kang - Please be sure to accept the answer if it worked for you.  Thanks.

Comment: @David Kang - If you images are hosted from [http://localhost/test/<imagename>.png](http://localhost/test/<imagename>.png), where is your Silverlight application hosted from?

Comment: @David Kang - Please see if the edits within my answer apply to your situation.

Comment: Oh, I got a another solution Robert. kkk

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is clientaccesspolicy.xml problem. When the address of the site where SL is loaded is different from address where you want download data from, than it can be blocked. That clientaccesspolicy.xml file also must specify that SL can go deeper into subdirs. ([here](http://franssenden.wordpress.com/2009/04/08/silverlight-client-access-policy-solves-crossdomain-issue/) is some example).

Now I realize, that this problem would throw some cross domain policy error...
Either way, check that too, just to be sure.